# Can't convert System.Object[] to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: collections, ienumerable, generics, icollection

I have a method with an object parameter.

```
public bool ContainsValue(object value)
```

I found that converting the object to an `IList` works.

```
IList<object> list = (IList<object>)value;
```

However, converting it to a `List` does not.

```
List<object> Ilist = (List<object>)value;
```

I looked at the definition of both the `IList` and the `List` and they both seem to implement the `Enumerator` and `Collection` interfaces.  I am wondering why `List` doesn't work but `IList` does.  Where in the framework does it crash and why?

Comment: First problem: Why is your parameter declared as type `object` in the first place? You're obviously using a version of the Framework that supports generics: **use them**. Second problem: you forgot to tell us what type your `object` instance is.

Answer (score 1):

Not a C# expert, but might it be that `IList` is an interface while `List` is an implementation? It might be another implementation of `IList` ...

Answer (score 0):

If an object implements the IList interface, it doesn't mean that it is actually of the type List. It can be any other type implementing the IList interface.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you have two problems:

1. An `IList` is not necessarily a `List`.
2. The parameter for `ContainsValue` should probably be something more specific than `object`.

*However*, if for some reason the parameter must remain and `object`, and you require a `List`, rather than an `IList`, you can do this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<object> list = ((IList<object>)value).ToList();
```